# Will Falcon 9 block 5 successful launch speed up production of BFR?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, spacex-super-heavy

I was just wondering that as Spacex has just launched it's final variant of Falcon 9 block 5 successfully, so now will it speed up the process of building BFR rocket ?

Comment: As opposed to it having not been successful, sure. The workforce that would have been assigned to diagnosing and remedying the failure can be instead applied to BFR development. Assuming that there's not something else more critical work on right now.

Answer (score 4):

More likely the successful relaunch and reuse of Block 5 will speed up BFR production.

If the Block 5 is successful, and works for rapid and cheap reuse, then the resources from Falcon 9 will not be as neccasary for future development rather than just producing enough cores and second stages to close out the program.